# supersized jquery plugin and slide_links

Tags: jquery, supersized

I would really like to add navigation to my slide show, and I can't get slide_links to work as described in the documentation. In the documentation on the Supersized site, the options are false, number, name and empty. In the comments within the demo files, the options are false, num, name and blank. Num and number don't seem to do anything at all. How can I make this work successfully?

It appears, according to the documentation, that slide_links should generate a list of links directly to the slides. It does not work as described. "Number" seems to be the option I am looking for, so I can create other links with those numbers and link directly to slides (say slide 5 of 10).

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you need. Try out this code, this should work.

```
jQuery(function($){

    $.supersized({  

    // Functionality
    slide_interval    :   3000,
    transition        :   1, 
    transition_speed  :   700, 

    // Components                           
    slide_links     :'blank',
    slides          :[ {image : '...'}] //put links for each slide

    thumb_links     :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation


    });
});
```

Comment: This is not what I need. This code actually generates an error "number is not defined". Also, you are defining slide_links twice. I tried both 'num' and 'number' in quotes before, which doesn't throw any errors, but also doesn't do anything. What I need is to directly link to, for example, slide 5 of 10.